# How to check if one date is smaller than the other, if it is return one result

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT data->>'input_timestamp' as input_timestamp,
       data->>'forcasted_timestamp' as forecasted_timestamp
from products
WHERE data->>'product_id' = '1'
```

I have 2 timestamps here, input_timestamp and forecasted_timestamp, this returns ALL the results. (Some like 3k)

I want to simply return 'true' if `input_timestamp` is greater than `forecasted_timestamp` in ANY of the records in my table products table. so this would mean, I would get one result back. Would I need to use GROUP BY or some sort of similar nature to achieve this?

Doing this in postgresql. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bool_or()`:

```
SELECT bool_or(bpg.data->>'input_timestamp' > bpg.data->>'forcasted_timestamp') as flag
FROM pricing.simulation_strategy bpg
WHERE bpg.data->>'product_level_2_id' = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be:

```
    SELECT bpg.data->>'input_timestamp' as input_timestamp,
           bpg.data->>'forcasted_timestamp' as forecasted_timestamp
    FROM pricing.simulation_strategy bpg
    WHERE bpg.data->>'product_level_2_id' = '1'
          AND bpg.data->>'input_timestamp' > bpg.data->>'forcasted_timestamp';
```